# Find image TAG and replace the source with a domain name

Tags: jquery

I am trying to work on a Jquery code which can find `src` of all `<img>` tags in the page and replace and append that with https://s3.amazonaws.com/abc so for example

```
<img src="/v/abx/templates/210/images/clear1x1.gif" width="5" height="5" alt="" />
```

Should be replaced with

```
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/abc/v/abx/templates/210/images/clear1x1.gif" width="5" height="5" alt="" />
```

The Main issue is it should happen on page Load

I have the following Javascript code but it doesnt work

```
<!-- START: javascript to manipulate product photo URLs -->
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.href.indexOf(‘/product_p/’) != -1) {
var ThisPhoto=document.getElementById('product_photo').src;
var ImgServer='https://s3.amazonaws.com/abc';
var ThisDomain=document.domain;
var NewImgSrc = ThisPhoto.replace(ThisDomain,ImgServer);
document.getElementById('product_photo').src=NewImgSrc;
}
</script>
<!-- END: javascript to manipulate product photo URLs -->
```

Comment: `My following Javascript code`.. I don't know whether you just forgot to add the code or if you're asking us to do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src','https://s3.amazonaws.com/abc/'+$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Put that in a `$(document).ready` handler.

Comment: I tried implementing your code at http://tinyurl.com/cfmwc3t you can do view-source on line 11-19, its still loading most of the images from live site instead from amazon